# Convert a queryset to json using tastypie resource

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a tastypie resource for a model. I also have a view which comes up with a queryset which needs to be serialised and sent to client. I am looking for a way to let tastypie resource handle the serialisation and dehydration of the queryset.

I see that I can pass a single object to

```
[Resource.build_bundle(self, obj=None, data=None, request=None)][1]
```

to create a bundle and then pass the bundle to

```
[Resource.full_dehydrate(self, bundle)][2]
```

and finally call

```
[Resource.serialize(self, request, data, format, options=None)][3]
```

on the dehydrated data.

But I want to convert full queryset to json and not just a single object. Maybe all I need is a way to convert full queryset to bundle.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was bugging me too, but I think I found the answer after looking through tastypie's code on github.

This will make a bunch of bundles.

```
bundles = [Resource.build_bundle(obj=q, request=request) for q in Queryset]
```

This will perform the dehydration.

```
data = [Resource.full_dehydrate(bundle) for bundle in bundles]
```

This will perform the serialization.

```
Resource.serialize(None, data, 'application/json'),
```

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to adapt this to a specical case where instead of a queryset, you have a single model instance for example. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/56089257/522150