# Using dehydrate in Tastypie to return all objects

Tags: python, django, tastypie

`Reward.objects.get()` returns an object, but how in Python/Django can I return all objects serialized for Tastypie?

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    res = super(SchemeResource, self).obj_update(bundle)
    rewards = Reward.objects.get()
    bundle.data['reward_participants'] = rewards
    return res
```

i.e. above gives me `<Reward object>` and not a list of all the rewards.

Comment: I think what you are asking for is a dict of objects to be returned try [st.__dict__ for st in rewards]

Comment: also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565975/convert-a-queryset-to-json-using-tastypie-resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want this:

```
rewards = Reward.objects.all()
```

instead of `rewards = Reward.objects.get()`. You can then iterate over the rewards query object to access the data in each row, if necessary. For example,

```
rewards = Reward.objects.all()
rewards = [(x.id, x.name) for x in rewards]  # returns a list of tuples for the id and name fields (if such fields exist)
```

Comment: even with 'all' Tastypie in the json still only shows <Reward object> for each :(

Comment: @Spike You have to iterate over the <Reward object> in order to access its contents. For example, [(r.id, r.name) for r in reward] would return a list of tuples with the id and name field values (or replace these two fields with whatever fields you have).

Answer (score 3):

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    res = super(SchemeResource, self).obj_update(bundle)
    rewards = Reward.objects.all()
    bundle.data['reward_participants'] = [model_to_dict(r) for r in rewards]
    return res
```

This works like a charm for me :)

Comment: Please explain what model_to_dict is.

Comment: @MikeStoddart model_to_dict is a function to turn a queryset into a python dictionary