# How to convert a Django model instance to JSON using existing Tastypie Resource?

Tags: json, django, tastypie

This problem is related to [this other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565975/convert-a-queryset-to-json-using-tastypie-resource), but instead, I wish to convert a single model instance to JSON, using an existing Tastypie Resource.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @grimygoop for the hint, I managed to create a method that can serialize any Django model instance to JSON using the associated Tastypie Resource. Here's how the procedure works...

```
def res_serialize(request, resource, obj):
    data = resource.full_dehydrate(resource.build_bundle(obj=obj, request=request))
    return resource.serialize(None, data, 'application/json')
```

To use this, you must have already defined a Resource class, and must also have a request object for this to work as expected. You'd then perform the serialization as such:

```
res_serialize(request,ClientResource(),client)
```

Note `ClientResource()` in the invocation above - we must pass the Resource instance, not just the class reference. So, in the above example, the object `client` gets serialized to JSON via the associated resource class. This can for example help in custom views where you wish to return a serialized instance of the object.

Also, a slight modification of this can handle querysets instead of single objects.